# Google Calendar Events API throwing error

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have my application authenticated using OAuth - and I've tested it with the calendar API. Everything works. I also used the "quick add" method for the events API, and that worked fine. But when I tried to insert using the following code

```
$event = new Event();
$event->setSummary('hello there');
$event->setLocation('America/Los_Angeles');
$start = new EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2012-04-19');
$event->setStart($start);
$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('myemail@gmail.com', $event);
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message
>   'Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/myemail@gmail.com/events?key=AIzaSyBddYIgnZJrXHuT8gvX-0tEypxsycw99rA:
>   (400) Bad Request' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uis\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiREST.php:86 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uis\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiREST.php(56):
>   apiREST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(apiHttpRequest)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uis\google-api-php-client\src\service\apiServiceResource.php(187):
>   apiREST::execute(Object(apiServiceRequest)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uis\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\apiCalendarService.php(493):
>   apiServiceResource->__call('insert', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uis\google-api-php-client\examples\calendar\cal.php(44):
>   EventsServiceResource->insert('paine1591@gmail...', Object(Event)) #4
>   {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\uis\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiREST.php on line
>   86

with myemail@gmail.com being the ID of my calendar. It works for everything else.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're not setting the attendees of the event.

Example:

```
$end = new EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$event->end = $end;

$attendee1 = new EventAttendee();
$attendee1->email = 'attendeeEmail';

$attendees = array($attendee1, ...);
$event->attendees = $attendees;
```